# Добавить новое поле в объект внутри массива

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, в чём ошибка. Хочу добавить поле age в каждый объект массива

```js
const arr = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];

const addNew = (arr) => {
  const copyArr = [...arr];
  const result = copyArr.forEach((el) => {
    el["age"] = "23";
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(addNew(arr), "res");
```

Comment: если массив преобразуете, то используйте `map`

Comment: а так `forEach` не возвращает результата чтобы его вернуть потом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в новом объекте вам нужна копия, так чтобы старый объект не менялся. Ошибку вам объяснили в других ответах и предложили решение. Однако есть один нюанс. К сожалению, вам мало скопировать набор объектов в новый массив, поскольку сами объекты в новом и старом массиве будут одними и теми же и будут меняться синхронно:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];

const addNew = (arr) => {
  return [...arr].map(el => { el["age"] = "23"; return el; });
};

console.log(addNew(arr));
console.log(arr);

// [ { name: 'John', age: '23' }, { name: 'Koul', age: '23' } ]
// [ { name: 'John', age: '23' }, { name: 'Koul', age: '23' } ]
```

Для полноценной копии вам нужно также создать копии объектов. Например, такими двумя способами:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];

const addNew1 = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(el => ({ ...el, age: '23' }));
};

const addNew2 = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(el => Object.assign({}, el, { age: '24' }));
};

console.log(addNew1(arr));
console.log(addNew2(arr));
console.log(arr);

// [ { name: 'John', age: '23' }, { name: 'Koul', age: '23' } ]
// [ { name: 'John', age: '24' }, { name: 'Koul', age: '24' } ]
// [ { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Koul' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

forEach мутирует сам массив и возвращает undefined

```
const arr = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];
const addNew = (arr) => {
  const copyArr = [...arr];
  copyArr.forEach(el => {
    el["age"] = "23";
  });
  return copyArr;
};

console.log(addNew(arr), "res");
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
      const hhh = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];

      const addField = (arr) => {
        const copyArr = [...arr];
        const result = copyArr.map((el) => {
          el["type"] = "adult";
          return el;
        });
        return result;
      };

      console.log(addField(hhh), "res");
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так. Поскольку forEach ничего не возращает

```js
const arr = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Koul" }];

const addNew = arr => [...arr].map(el => {
    el.age = "23"; return el;
  })

console.log(addNew(arr), "res");
```

Comment: человек спрашивает, в чем ошибка, а не как сделать

Comment: @teran Исправил добавил комментарий. Тем кто минусует если не трудно пояснить

Answer (score -2):

```
const arr = [{
    name: "John"
}, {
    name: "Koul"
}];

const addNew = (arr) => {
    const copyArr = [...arr];
let res = [];
copyArr.map((el) => {
    el["age"] = "23";
    res.push(el)
});
return res;
};

console.log(addNew(arr), "res");
```